# アナログ時計のサイズを切り替える方法

Tags: javascript, html

下記の3つのソース(＊２つは補間用)は、アナログ時計(マウスストーカー)のサイズを
"BIGGER⇔ORIGINAL"と*１つの部屋で行われている*ように見せかけたものです。
こんな泥臭い手法でなく、もっとスマートに"１つのソース"でいいように、あれこれ
試行錯誤していますが、うまくいきません。ソース自体に無理があるのかもしれません。
１つのソースで"BIGGER⇔ORIGINAL"と**アナログ時計のサイズを切り替える方法**があれば、
ご教示ください。
なお、それぞれのソースの"ファイル名"は、次の通りです。
・１つ目のソース…実験1.html
・２つ目のソース…実験2.html
・２つ目のソース…実験3.html

(１つ目のソース)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis"> 

<TITLE>妖怪クロック(アナログ)- JavaScript</TITLE>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.butt{
BACKGROUND:maroon; 
COLOR:gold;
}
//-->
</style>


<BODY bgcolor="black" text="white">

<div id="clock" style="visibility:hidden">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function(){
    "use strict";

function $(sel)
{
    return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel)
{
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
    {
        return document.getElementsByName(sel);
    }
    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

var dCol = '', //date colour.
    sCol = '', //seconds colour.
    mCol = '', //minutes colour.
    hCol = '', //hours colour.
    fCol = '', //face color

    ClockHeight = 50,
    ClockWidth = 50,
    ClockFromMouseY = 0,
    ClockFromMouseX = 100,
    d = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    date = new Date(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    year = date.getYear() + 1900;
var TodaysDate = " " + d[date.getDay()] + " " + day + " " + m[date.getMonth()] + " " + year;
var D = TodaysDate.split('');
var H = '☆☆☆';
    H = H.split('');
var M = '☆☆☆☆';
    M = M.split('');
var S = '・・・・・';
    S = S.split('');
var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
    font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    size = 1,
    speed = 0.45;
    Face = Face.split(' ');
var n = Face.length;
var a = size * 10;
var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0,
    scrll = 0,
    props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">',
    props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
var Split = 360 / n;
var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
var HandY = -7,
    HandX = -2.5,
    step = 0.02,
    currStep = 0,
    y = [],
    x = [],
    Y = [],
    X = [],
    Dy = [],
    Dx = [],
    DY = [],
    DX = [];
var i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    y[i] = 0;
    x[i] = 0;
    Y[i] = 0;
    X[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
{
    Dy[i] = 0;
    Dx[i] = 0;
    DY[i] = 0;
    DX[i] = 0;
}
var wrapper = $('clock');
var html = '';
// Date wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Face wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Hours wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Minute wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Seconds wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Mouse move event handler

function Mouse(evnt) 
{
    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
    {
        ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
}

document.onmousemove = Mouse;

function ClockAndAssign() 
{
    var time = new Date();
    var secs = time.getSeconds();
    var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
    var mins = time.getMinutes();
    var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
    var hr = time.getHours();
    var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
    $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var F = $$('Face')[i];
        F.style.top = y[i] + ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        F.style.left = x[i] + ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
        HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
        HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
    {
        var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
        ML.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
        ML.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
    {
        var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
        SL.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
        SL.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
    {
        var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
        DL.top = Dy[i] + ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        DL.left = Dx[i] + ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    currStep -= step;
}

function Delay() 
{
    scrll = 0;
    Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
    Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
        Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
        Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);
    }
    y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
    x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
        x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
    }
    ClockAndAssign();
    setTimeout(Delay, 20);
}

Delay();

}());

num = 1;
function toggle(){
 num ^= 1; 
 if(num == 1){ 
document.getElementById('Od').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Of').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Oh').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Om').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Os').style.visibility="hidden";
 }
else { 
document.getElementById('Od').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Of').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Oh').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Om').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Os').style.visibility="visible";
} 
document.getElementById("tog").value = num ?" APPEAR ":"KILL(切る)";
}
</script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center><p>
<input class="butt" type="button" id="tog" value="今何時？" onclick="toggle();">
<input class="butt" type="button" value="BIGGER" onclick="location.href='実験2.html';">
</p></center>

</body>
</html>
```

(２つ目のソース)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis"> 

<TITLE>妖怪クロック(アナログ) - JavaScript</TITLE>

<style type="text/css">
<!--//
.butt{
BACKGROUND:maroon; 
COLOR:gold;
}
//-->
</style>


<BODY bgcolor="black" text="white">

<div id="clock">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function(){
    "use strict";

function $(sel)
{
    return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel)
{
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
    {
        return document.getElementsByName(sel);
    }
    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

var dCol = '', //date colour.
    sCol = '', //seconds colour.
    mCol = '', //minutes colour.
    hCol = '', //hours colour.
    fCol = '', //face color

    ClockHeight = 130,
    ClockWidth = 130,
    ClockFromMouseY = 0,
    ClockFromMouseX = 100,
    d = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    date = new Date(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    year = date.getYear() + 1900;
var TodaysDate = " " + d[date.getDay()] + " " + day + " " + m[date.getMonth()] + " " + year;
var D = TodaysDate.split('');
var H = '☆☆☆';
    H = H.split('');
var M = '☆☆☆☆';
    M = M.split('');
var S = '・・・・・';
    S = S.split('');
var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
    font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    size = 1,
    speed = 0.45;
    Face = Face.split(' ');
var n = Face.length;
var a = size * 10;
var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0,
    scrll = 0,
    props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">',
    props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
var Split = 360 / n;
var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
var HandY = -7,
    HandX = -2.5,
    step = 0.02,
    currStep = 0,
    y = [],
    x = [],
    Y = [],
    X = [],
    Dy = [],
    Dx = [],
    DY = [],
    DX = [];
var i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    y[i] = 0;
    x[i] = 0;
    Y[i] = 0;
    X[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
{
    Dy[i] = 0;
    Dx[i] = 0;
    DY[i] = 0;
    DX[i] = 0;
}
var wrapper = $('clock');
var html = '';
// Date wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Face wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Hours wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Minute wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Seconds wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Mouse move event handler

function Mouse(evnt) 
{
    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
    {
        ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
}

document.onmousemove = Mouse;

function ClockAndAssign() 
{
    var time = new Date();
    var secs = time.getSeconds();
    var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
    var mins = time.getMinutes();
    var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
    var hr = time.getHours();
    var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
    $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var F = $$('Face')[i];
        F.style.top = y[i] + ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        F.style.left = x[i] + ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
        HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
        HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
    {
        var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
        ML.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
        ML.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
    {
        var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
        SL.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
        SL.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
    {
        var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
        DL.top = Dy[i] + ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        DL.left = Dx[i] + ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    currStep -= step;
}

function Delay() 
{
    scrll = 0;
    Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
    Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
        Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
        Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);
    }
    y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
    x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
        x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
    }
    ClockAndAssign();
    setTimeout(Delay, 20);
}

Delay();

}());

num = 1;
function toggle(){
 num ^=  1;
 if(num == 1){
document.getElementById('Od').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Of').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Oh').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Om').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Os').style.visibility="visible";
 }
else { 
document.getElementById('Od').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Of').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Oh').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Om').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Os').style.visibility="hidden";
} 
document.getElementById("tog").value = num ?"KILL(切る)":" APPEAR ";
}
</script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center><p>
<input class="butt" type="button" id="tog" value="KILL(切る)" onclick="toggle()">
<input class="butt" type="button" value="ORIGINAL" onclick="location.href='実験3.html'">
</p></center>

</body>
</html>
```

(３つ目のソース)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis"> 

<TITLE>妖怪クロック(アナログ) - JavaScript</TITLE>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.butt{
BACKGROUND:maroon; 
COLOR:gold;
}
//-->
</style>


<BODY bgcolor="black" text="white">

<div id="clock">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function(){
    "use strict";

function $(sel)
{
    return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel)
{
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
    {
        return document.getElementsByName(sel);
    }
    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

var dCol = '', //date colour.
    sCol = '', //seconds colour.
    mCol = '', //minutes colour.
    hCol = '', //hours colour.
    fCol = '', //face color

    ClockHeight = 50,
    ClockWidth = 50,
    ClockFromMouseY = 0,
    ClockFromMouseX = 100,
    d = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    date = new Date(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    year = date.getYear() + 1900;
var TodaysDate = " " + d[date.getDay()] + " " + day + " " + m[date.getMonth()] + " " + year;
var D = TodaysDate.split('');
var H = '☆☆☆';
    H = H.split('');
var M = '☆☆☆☆';
    M = M.split('');
var S = '・・・・・';
    S = S.split('');
var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
    font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    size = 1,
    speed = 0.45;
    Face = Face.split(' ');
var n = Face.length;
var a = size * 10;
var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0,
    scrll = 0,
    props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">',
    props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
var Split = 360 / n;
var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
var HandY = -7,
    HandX = -2.5,
    step = 0.02,
    currStep = 0,
    y = [],
    x = [],
    Y = [],
    X = [],
    Dy = [],
    Dx = [],
    DY = [],
    DX = [];
var i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    y[i] = 0;
    x[i] = 0;
    Y[i] = 0;
    X[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
{
    Dy[i] = 0;
    Dx[i] = 0;
    DY[i] = 0;
    DX[i] = 0;
}
var wrapper = $('clock');
var html = '';
// Date wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Face wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Hours wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Minute wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Seconds wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Mouse move event handler

function Mouse(evnt) 
{
    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
    {
        ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
}

document.onmousemove = Mouse;

function ClockAndAssign() 
{
    var time = new Date();
    var secs = time.getSeconds();
    var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
    var mins = time.getMinutes();
    var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
    var hr = time.getHours();
    var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
    $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var F = $$('Face')[i];
        F.style.top = y[i] + ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        F.style.left = x[i] + ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
        HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
        HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
    {
        var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
        ML.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
        ML.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
    {
        var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
        SL.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
        SL.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
    {
        var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
        DL.top = Dy[i] + ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        DL.left = Dx[i] + ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    currStep -= step;
}

function Delay() 
{
    scrll = 0;
    Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
    Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
        Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
        Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);
    }
    y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
    x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
        x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
    }
    ClockAndAssign();
    setTimeout(Delay, 20);
}

Delay();

}());

num = 0;
function toggle(){
 num ^= 1; 
 if(num == 1){ 
document.getElementById('Od').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Of').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Oh').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Om').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Os').style.visibility="hidden";
 }
else { 
document.getElementById('Od').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Of').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Oh').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Om').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Os').style.visibility="visible";
} 
document.getElementById("tog").value = num ?" APPEAR ":"Kill(切る)";
}
</script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center><p>
<input class="butt" type="button" id="tog" value="KILL(切る)" onclick="toggle();">
<input class="butt" type="button" value="BIGGER" onclick="location.href='実験2.html';">
</p></center>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

スケールを表す状態変数を導入し、描画のタイミングで値のトランジションを行うのが良いのではないでしょうか。

状態変数

```
var scale = 1;
var transitionStarted = 0;
var transitionFrom = 0;
var transitionTo = 0;
var transitionDuration = 0;
```

トランジション処理

```
function ClockAndAssign() 
{
    var time = new Date();
    // スケールの変更処理
    if(transitionStarted)
    {
        var d = time.getTime() - transitionStarted;
        if (d < transitionDuration)
        {
            scale = transitionFrom + (transitionTo - transitionFrom) * d / transitionDuration;
        }
        else
        {
            // トランジション終了
            scale = transitionTo;
            transitionStarted = 0;
        }
    }
    /* 略 */
    // 各半径にスケールをかける
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var F = $$('Face')[i];
        F.style.top = y[i] + scale * ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        F.style.left = x[i] + scale * ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    /* 略 */
}
```

アニメーションの開始時には以下のように変数を設定します。

```
transitionStarted = new Date().getTime();
transitionFrom = scale;
transitionTo = 2; // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
transitionDuration = 1000;
```

また`d / transitionDuration`の部分にイージング関数を適用することも出来ます。

### 適用例

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis"> 

<TITLE>妖怪クロック(アナログ) - JavaScript</TITLE>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.butt{
BACKGROUND:maroon; 
COLOR:gold;
}
//-->
</style>


<BODY bgcolor="black" text="white">

<div id="clock">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

// 状態変数
var scale = 1;
var transitionStarted = 0;
var transitionFrom = 0;
var transitionTo = 0;
var transitionDuration = 0;

// サイズの変更を開始する処理
function toBigger()
{
    transitionStarted = new Date().getTime();
    transitionFrom = scale;
    transitionTo = 2; // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
    transitionDuration = 1000;
}

(function(){
    "use strict";

function $(sel)
{
    return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel)
{
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
    {
        return document.getElementsByName(sel);
    }
    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

var dCol = '', //date colour.
    sCol = '', //seconds colour.
    mCol = '', //minutes colour.
    hCol = '', //hours colour.
    fCol = '', //face color

    ClockHeight = 50,
    ClockWidth = 50,
    ClockFromMouseY = 0,
    ClockFromMouseX = 100,
    d = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    date = new Date(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    year = date.getYear() + 1900;
var TodaysDate = " " + d[date.getDay()] + " " + day + " " + m[date.getMonth()] + " " + year;
var D = TodaysDate.split('');
var H = '☆☆☆';
    H = H.split('');
var M = '☆☆☆☆';
    M = M.split('');
var S = '・・・・・';
    S = S.split('');
var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
    font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    size = 1,
    speed = 0.45;
    Face = Face.split(' ');
var n = Face.length;
var a = size * 10;
var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0,
    scrll = 0,
    props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">',
    props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
var Split = 360 / n;
var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
var HandY = -7,
    HandX = -2.5,
    step = 0.02,
    currStep = 0,
    y = [],
    x = [],
    Y = [],
    X = [],
    Dy = [],
    Dx = [],
    DY = [],
    DX = [];
var i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    y[i] = 0;
    x[i] = 0;
    Y[i] = 0;
    X[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
{
    Dy[i] = 0;
    Dx[i] = 0;
    DY[i] = 0;
    DX[i] = 0;
}
var wrapper = $('clock');
var html = '';
// Date wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Face wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Hours wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Minute wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Seconds wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Mouse move event handler

function Mouse(evnt) 
{
    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
    {
        ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
}

document.onmousemove = Mouse;

function ClockAndAssign() 
{
    var time = new Date();
    
    // 状態変更処理
    if(transitionStarted)
    {
        var d = time.getTime() - transitionStarted;
        if (d < transitionDuration)
        {
            scale = transitionFrom + (transitionTo - transitionFrom) * d / transitionDuration;
        }
        else
        {
            // トランジション終了
            scale = transitionTo;
            transitionStarted = 0;
        }
    }
    
    var secs = time.getSeconds();
    var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
    var mins = time.getMinutes();
    var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
    var hr = time.getHours();
    var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
    $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var F = $$('Face')[i];
        F.style.top = y[i] + scale * ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        F.style.left = x[i] + scale * ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
        HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + scale * (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
        HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + scale * (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
    {
        var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
        ML.top = y[i] + HandY + scale * (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
        ML.left = x[i] + HandX + scale * (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
    {
        var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
        SL.top = y[i] + HandY + scale * (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
        SL.left = x[i] + HandX + scale * (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
    {
        var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
        DL.top = Dy[i] + scale * ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        DL.left = Dx[i] + scale * ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    currStep -= step;
}

function Delay() 
{
    scrll = 0;
    Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
    Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
        Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
        Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);
    }
    y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
    x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
        x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
    }
    ClockAndAssign();
    setTimeout(Delay, 20);
}

Delay();

}());

num = 0;
function toggle(){
 num ^= 1; 
 if(num == 1){ 
document.getElementById('Od').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Of').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Oh').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Om').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Os').style.visibility="hidden";
 }
else { 
document.getElementById('Od').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Of').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Oh').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Om').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Os').style.visibility="visible";
} 
document.getElementById("tog").value = num ?" APPEAR ":"Kill(切る)";
}
</script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center><p>
<input class="butt" type="button" id="tog" value="KILL(切る)" onclick="toggle();">
<input class="butt" type="button" value="BIGGER" onclick="toBigger()">
</p></center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ボタンとリンクさせて、どのようにしたら"BIGGER"⇔"ORIGINAL"と切り替えられるのか分からないです。

お手数ですが、全体の完成ソースを送っていただけたら、幸いです。

Comment: @user9359 丸投げはあまり褒められた行為ではありません。回答に応じてどう実装してどこが分からないのかを質問に追記すべきかと思います。動作確認コードは追記しましたが、要件は満たしていないので不明な点があれば再度コメントしてください。

Comment: おっしゃる通りです。
見たこともなかったので、頭の中が真っ白になりました。

『BIGGER⇔ORIGINAL』と繰り返し切り替えるには、条件節で
組み立てる必要があるでしょうね。また、試行錯誤してみます。

やろうと思えば、できるものですね。
切り替わり方が、モワっと真ん中から大きくなって驚きました。

Comment: 分けもわからず弄くっていましたら、うまくいきました(笑)

追加，及び変更箇所は次の通りです。

<div id="clock" style="visibility:hidden">

function toBigger(){
{
    transitionStarted = new Date().getTime();
    transitionFrom = scale;
    transitionTo = 3; // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
    transitionDuration = 1000;
}
if(transitionFrom==scale){
document.getElementById("tog1").value= "ORIGINAL";
    transitionTo = 3; // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
    transitionDuration = 1000;
}
if(transitionFrom==3){
document.getElementById("tog1").value= "BIGGER";
    transitionTo =  1; // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
    transitionDuration = 1000;
}
｝

それと、ボタンにid=tog1です。

専門的には、如何ですか？

Comment: 重複していました。下記のほうが、正解のようですね？
これで、ソースがスッキリ１つにまとまり、先に進めます。

function toBigger(){
{
    transitionStarted = new Date().getTime();
    transitionFrom = scale;
    transitionTo = 3; // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
    transitionDuration = 1000;
document.getElementById("tog1").value= "ORIGINAL";
}
if(transitionFrom==3){
    transitionTo =  1; // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
    transitionDuration = 1000;
document.getElementById("tog1").value= " BIGGER ";
}
}